# FunctionPeriod for functions defined in a Piecewise manner

Tags: piecewise, periodic-function

To create a minimal example, consider a piecewise function:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := 1 /; 0 <= x <= 1;
f[x_] := -x /; -1 <= x < 0;
f[x_] := f[x - 2] /; x > 1;
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 5}]
```

[image]

```
FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]
```

returns `0`.

**Question**: What is the method to calculate function period for functions defined in a piecewise manner?

---

**Context**

This is an example from `Abell/Braselton's Mathematica by Example` Revised edition Page 286 (fairly old version), where the authors calculate Fourier Series coefficients for this waveform from first principles using Mathematica (a period of 2 is assumed). I wanted to do this using built-in commands but failed. user64494 identified the problem that the waveform is not periodic as defined and suggested an answer that does allow `FourierTrigSeries` to be calculated. I have to study these solutions further and compare to see if I have more queries. Thanks.

Comment: Mathematica is right: the result of `Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 5}]` clearly shows that your `f[x]` is not defined for `x<-1`.

Comment: To define it for `x<-1`: `Clear[f];
f[x_] := 1 /; 0 <= Mod[x, 2] <= 1;
f[x_] := -Mod[x, 2] + 2 /; 1 < Mod[x, 2] ;` and plot: `Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}]`. The `FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]` still gets 0. So is it the explicit use of `Piecewise` that is enabling the calculation?

Comment: Your modified construction is too complicate for WL. E.g. try `FunctionDomain[f[x], x, Reals]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your construction of `f[x]` is too complicate for `FunctionPeriod`. If we rewrite the function under consideration as a piece-wise function, then `FunctionPeriod` works well.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, Mod[x, 2] >= 0 && Mod[x, 2] <= 1}, {-Mod[x, 2] + 2, 
Mod[x, 2] > 1}}]
FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]
```

> `2`

Answer (score 2):

One could also say that the definition is not complicated enough. Replace the third definition thus:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := 1 /; 0 <= x <= 1;
f[x_] := -x /; -1 <= x < 0;
f[x_] := f[Mod[x, 2, -1]] /; ! MatchQ[x, Mod[_, 2, -1]];

FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]
(*  2  *)
```

I believe that `FunctionDomain[expr, x]` analyzes the literal expression `expr`, not its full definition. Since `f[x]` evaluates to `f[x]`, it is analyzed as though it were an undefined `g[x]` and has no (positive) period.  Thus the period returned is `0`. But if the expression `expr` is written in terms of a periodic function, then `FunctionPeriod` may succeed, even if it's `f[Mod[x, 2, -1]]` or  `g[Mod[x, 2, -1]]` where `f` and `g` are treated as an unknown function.

Comment: `FunctionDomain[f[x], x]` returns `FunctionDomain[f[Mod[x, 2, -1]], x]` and a message "FunctionDomain::nmet: Unable to find the domain with the available methods.".

Comment: Seems a completely irrelevant comment. If you have another question to ask, click the "Ask Question" button.